# Set Card game going into infinite loop with 2 players

Tags: java, arrays, oop

here is a card game with Java. The rules of the game are posted below

```
● There are 50 cards
● Each card is a colour out of red, green, blue, yellow, and purple
● Each card have a value between 1 to 10

To play Cody’s Card game, you have 3 players. Each player plays a card from the top of
their hand and they are compared to each other. Whoever has the highest value wins all 3
cards. If there is a tie for the highest value, the winner will be in order of the colour
(Red>Green>Blue>Yellow>Purple).

Here are 3 examples:

Round 1:
Player 1 = Red 5
Player 2 = Blue 3
Player 3 = Purple 10

Player 3 wins

Round 2:
Player 1 = Red 5
Player 2 = Blue 5
Player 3 = Purple 10

Player 3 wins

Round 3:
Player 1 = Red 5
Player 2 = Blue 5
Player 3 = Purple 1

Player 1 wins

As with war, the game goes until one player has all of the cards. Once one player is out, the
game continues with only 2 players. Your program should output each round and who wins. Make the program ask if you want to play again when the game is finished. As well make the program ask for the 3 player names in the beginning.
```

So the program works fine for 3 players. But with 2 players the game always goes to a infinite loop, continously exchanging cards between the 2 players.

here is the function to assign the cards (only called at the beginning of the game)

```java
 /**
     * Returns a specific number of cards to the player. Also removes the assigned cards from allCardList
     *
     * @param name Player name
     * @param num  Number of cards to assign. (25 or 16)
     * @return List of cards for that specific player
     */
    static ArrayList<Card> assignCards(String name, int num) {

        int length;

        Random r = new Random();
        ArrayList<Card> a = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i <= num; i++) {
            length = allCards.size();
            if (allCards.size() == 0) {
                break;
            }

            int randId = r.nextInt(length);
            Card card = allCards.get(randId);
            card.playerName = name;
            a.add(card);
            allCards.remove(randId);
            if (allCards.size() == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return a;
    }
```

here is the code for 3 player game which actually works

```
 /**
     * Game loop for 3 players
     */
    static void play() {
//        Assign 16 cards to each player
        for (Player player : players) {
            player.playerCards.addAll(assignCards(player.playerName, 16));
        }

        do {
            dealCards();
        } while (shouldContinue());

//        Remove the lost player
        for (Player player : players) {
            if (player.playerCards.size() == 0) {
                players.remove(player);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

 static boolean shouldContinue() {
        for (Player player : players) {
            if (player.playerCards.size() == 0) {
                playerLostSb.append(player.playerName).append(" has been out!!!");
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


// the main thing

 static void dealCards() {
        ArrayList<Card> cardList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Player player : players) {
            Card playerCard = player.playerCards.get(0);
            cardList.add(playerCard);

            player.playerCards.remove(0);
             System.out.println(player.playerName + " " + playerCard);
        }

        Collections.sort(cardList);

        if (cardList.get(0) == cardList.get(1)) {
//            Check color
            if (cardList.get(0).color > cardList.get(1).color) {
                for (Player player : players) {
                    if (cardList.get(0).playerName.equals(player.playerName)) {
                        player.playerCards.addAll(cardList);
                        // System.out.println(cardList.get(0).playerName + " has won this round!");
                        if (slowModeEnabled) {
                            while (scanner.nextLine().equals("")) ;
                        }

                    }
                }
            } else {
                for (Player player : players) {
                    if (cardList.get(1).playerName.equals(player.playerName)) {
                        player.playerCards.addAll(cardList);
                        // System.out.println(cardList.get(2).playerName + " has won this round!");
                        if (slowModeEnabled) {
                            while (scanner.nextLine().equals("")) ;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            return;
        } else if ((players.size() > 2) && cardList.get(1) == cardList.get(2)) {
            if (cardList.get(1).color > cardList.get(2).color) {
                for (Player player : players) {
                    if (cardList.get(1).playerName.equals(player.playerName)) {
                        player.playerCards.addAll(cardList);
                        // System.out.println(cardList.get(1).playerName + " has won this round!");
                        if (slowModeEnabled) {
                            while (scanner.nextLine().equals("")) ;
                        }

                    }
                }
            } else {
                for (Player player : players) {
                    if (cardList.get(2).playerName.equals(player.playerName)) {
                        // System.out.println(cardList.get(2).playerName + " has won this round!");
                        if (slowModeEnabled) {
                            while (scanner.nextLine().equals("")) ;
                        }

                        player.playerCards.addAll(cardList);
                    }
                }
            }
            return;
        }

        Card highestCard = cardList.get(cardList.size() - 1);

        for (Player player : players) {
            if (highestCard.playerName.equals(player.playerName)) {
                // System.out.println(highestCard.playerName + " has won this round!");
                if (slowModeEnabled) {
                    while (scanner.nextLine().equals("")) ;
                }
                player.playerCards.addAll(cardList);
            }
        }

    }
```

after this runs, it removes the player who's `playerCards.size() == 0`

this is the code that goes into the infinite loop (2 player game)

```
    static void playWithTwoPlayers() {
        while (players.get(0).playerCards.size()!=0 || players.get(1).playerCards.size()!=0) {
            for (Player player : players) {
                if (player.playerCards.size() == 0) {
                    players.remove(player);
                    break;
                }
            }
            ArrayList<Card> cardList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Player player : players) {
                Card playerCard = player.playerCards.get(0);
                cardList.add(playerCard);
                player.playerCards.remove(0);
                // System.out.println(player.playerName + " " + playerCard);
            }
            Collections.sort(cardList);

            if(cardList.size() <1){System.out.println("asdfasdfasdf"); break;}


            if (cardList.get(0).value == cardList.get(1).value) {
                if (cardList.get(0).color > cardList.get(1).color) {
                    for (Player player : players) {
                        if (cardList.get(0).playerName.equals(player.playerName)) {

                            // System.out.println(cardList.get(0).playerName + " has won this round!");
                            if (slowModeEnabled) {
                                while (scanner.nextLine().equals("")) ;
                            }

                            player.playerCards.addAll(cardList);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    for (Player player : players) {
                        if (cardList.get(1).playerName.equals(player.playerName)) {
                            // System.out.println(cardList.get(1).playerName + " has won this round");
                            if (slowModeEnabled) {
                                while (scanner.nextLine().equals("")) ;
                            }
                            player.playerCards.addAll(cardList);
                        }
                    }
                }
                continue;
            }
            for (Player player : players) {
                if (player.playerName.equals(cardList.get(1).playerName)) {
                    // System.out.println(cardList.get(1).playerName + " has won this round!");
                    if (slowModeEnabled) {
                        while (scanner.nextLine().equals("")) ;
                    }
                    player.playerCards.addAll(cardList);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Steps I tried:
I tried to do the same logic for the 3 player and the 2 player game.
Printed the `player.playerCards.size()` but it is never equal to zero in 2 player game.
Tried stepping through the code but all the card exchange rules are being followed but still the game does not end

NOTE: Sometimes the game does end but after 10 - 20 minutes. The requirements state that the game should be over in like 1 minute which is not the case here

All help is appreciated. Thank You :)

EDIT:
Card.java

```
public class Card implements Comparable<Card> {
    static final int RED = 5, GREEN = 4, BLUE = 3, YELLOW = 2, PURPLE = 1;
    int value, color;
    String playerName;

    public Card(int value, int color) {
        this.value = value;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String colorName = "";
        switch (color) {
            case RED:
                colorName = "RED";
                break;
            case GREEN:
                colorName = "GREEN";
                break;
            case BLUE:
                colorName = "BLUE";
                break;
            case YELLOW:
                colorName = "YELLOW";
                break;
            case PURPLE:
                colorName = "purple";
                break;
        }
        return colorName + " " + value;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Card o) {
        return Integer.compareUnsigned(this.value,o.value);

    }
}
```

Player.java

```
public class Player {
    String playerName;
    ArrayList<Card> playerCards = new ArrayList<>();

    public Player(String playerName){
        this.playerName = playerName;
    }

}
```

main.java => All the code i posted above ie, the methods and the following code go in the Main.java file

```
 /**
     * Returns the 50 cards
     *
     * @return 50 Cards
     */
    static ArrayList<Card> makeAllCards() {
        ArrayList<Card> allCards = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            allCards.add(new Card(i, Card.RED));
            allCards.add(new Card(i, Card.PURPLE));
            allCards.add(new Card(i, Card.GREEN));
            allCards.add(new Card(i, Card.BLUE));
            allCards.add(new Card(i, Card.YELLOW));
        }
        return allCards;
    }
```

Main method

```
  //    Card List
    public static ArrayList<Card> allCards = new ArrayList<>();

    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    //    Player List
    static ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();
    static boolean slowModeEnabled = false;

    /**
     * Main function
     *
     * @param args Arguments for running the program
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Scanner object to receive inputs
        // System.out.println("Welcome to my Card game;");

        //Game loop with condition to check for user conformation
        do {
            //Adding the players to the list
            // System.out.println("Enter player 1 name");
            players.add(new Player(scanner.nextLine()));

            // System.out.println("Enter player 2 name");
            players.add(new Player(scanner.nextLine()));

            // System.out.println("Enter player 3 name");
            players.add(new Player(scanner.nextLine()));

            // System.out.println("Slowmode? y/n");
            if (scanner.nextLine().equals("y")) {
                slowModeEnabled = true;
            }

//            Add all the cards
            allCards = makeAllCards();

//            initial round
            play();



//            //            Remove all the cards and re assign them
//            for (Player player : players) {
//                player.playerCards.clear();
//                player.playerCards.addAll(assignCards(player.playerName, 25));
//            }

            //Second round
            for(Player player:players) {
                System.out.println(player.playerCards.size());
            }


            playWithTwoPlayers();

            // System.out.println(playerLostSb.toString());

             System.out.println(players.get(0).playerName + " has won the match");

             System.out.println("Press 'y' to continue again!");

        } while (scanner.nextLine().equals("y"));

//        Ending
        scanner.close();
        // System.out.println("Bye. ");
}
```

here is the full file (Main.java) : https://hatebin.com/cumavqvyff

Comment: Can you please edit your question with your main Method, Player class,... everything so that we can copy-paste it into our IDE and test it. I would also suggest that you add some  System.out calls in all the relevant places so that you can see what is happening. Or use a debugger.

Comment: Of course I will edit the question. Also I did add a ton of print statement and also used the debugger. But I'm unfortunately not able to figure it out

Comment: @JavaMan i have added all the code

Comment: so far I can already tell that if you initialize the Random with a fixed Seed 1 (so new Random(1)) you get an IndexOutOfBoundException...  if you use 42 instead of 1 then the program works fine.. but I have to investigate further ... use 3 and it continues forever

Comment: Oh thanks for that. All help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed your code

in your playWithTwoPlayers Method

```
if(cardList.size() <2){System.out.println("asdfasdfasdf"); break;} //2 instead of 1
```

In your dealCards Method

```
if ((players.size() > 2) && cardList.get(1).value == cardList.get(2).value) { // added the .value, you were comparing the objects, not the card values
```

Comment: umm for me it still goes into a infinite loop. i added both the things you said.. is it possible for you to upload the contents of Main.java as a whole to some service or update your answer?

Comment: also i added the seed to the random so now it is `new Random(42);`

Comment: I think the problem is that there are "cardlist" combinations for the player which lead to an infinite loop.... so if its always  A wins, B wins , A wins, B wins and so on... it will never end. You'll have to think about a logic which prevents this situation from happening .. i would suggest using Collections.shuffle(cardList); where you have Collections.sort(cardList) i

Comment: I am doing the Collection.sort to make it in ascending order

Comment: according to the rules i can not change anything

Answer (score 0):

Seems the reason for infinite loop is that `playWithTwoPlayers()` stops only when both players have no cards, which cannot happen.

```
while  player-0 has cards  OR  player-1 has cards
```

It should actually stop when all cards are held by a single player.
So the stop condition could be like this:

```
while (player_0_has_cards && player_1_has_cards) {
...
}
```

A different view of cards can help implementing this.

- Value: 1-10  -->  digit 0-9
- Color: 1-5

As result:

- Card is a unique number between 1 (01) to 95. (skipping some numbers)
- Round winner decided by max of N different numbers, N=2 or 3 (for example)
- Same code for any number of players.

**Edit**: adding more details

Easier to rewrite rather than debugging current code.

- three main classes: card, player, game.
- Player knows how to add/delete cards, and tell if it can play more

```
    String name;
    List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();

    Player(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    void putCard(Card card) {
        cards.add(card);
    }

    Card deleteCard() {
        return cards.remove(0);
    }

    boolean canPlay() {
        return !cards.isEmpty();
    }
```

- Color becomes a java enum.

```
    enum Color {
        PURPLE(1),
        YELLOW(2),
        BLUE(3),
        GREEN(4),
        RED(5);

        int rank;
        static Color[] colors = colors();

        Color(int rank) {
            this.rank = rank;
        }
    }
```

- Card comparison is simpler by using that integer weight mentioned above

```
    int value;
    Color color;
    int weight;

    Card(int value, Color color) {
        this.value = value;
        this.color = color;
        this.weight = (10 * value) + color.rank;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Card o) {
        return Integer.compare(o.weight, this.weight);
    }
```

- Same code handles any number of players.

```
        dealCards();
        int n = 0;
        while (players.size() > 1 && n < maxRounds) {
            playRound(++n);
        }
        if (players.size() == 1) {
            System.out.println("\nAnd the winner is: " + players.get(0).toString());
        } else {
            System.out.println("\nStopping as there's no winner after too many rounds: " + n);
        }
```

- Dealing initial cards

```
        List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int value = 1; value <= 10; value++) {
            for (Color color : Color.values()) {
                cards.add(new Card(value, color));
            }
        }
        Random r = new Random();
        int nextPlayer = 0;
        while (!cards.isEmpty()) {
            players.get(nextPlayer).putCard(cards.remove(r.nextInt(cards.size())));
            nextPlayer = (++nextPlayer) % players.size();
        }
```

- playRound() removes players that can no longer play

```
        Map<Card, Player> challenge = new HashMap<>();
        for (Player player : players) {
            Card card = player.deleteCard();
            challenge.put(card, player);
            System.out.println(player.toString() + " played card: " + card);
        }
        List<Card> keys = new ArrayList<>(challenge.keySet());
        Collections.sort(keys);

        Card winningCard = keys.get(0);
        Player winner = challenge.get(winningCard);
        for (Card card : keys) {
            winner.putCard(card);
        }

        for (int i = players.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (!players.get(i).canPlay()) {
                players.remove(i);
            }
        }
```

Comment: i have changed it to a && but still its not stopping

Comment: also could you provide a code sample for the differnet implementation... i dont get what you are saying... a repl.it would be of great help to me :)

Comment: @CodeYard what Doron means is that in your playWithTwoPlayers method 
while (players.get(0).playerCards.size()!=0 || players.get(1).playerCards.size()!=0) { should be  while (players.get(0).playerCards.size()!=0 && players.get(1).playerCards.size()!=0) {   //(this doesn't fix your problem but it && would make more sense

Comment: What i didn't understand

Comment: I changed the whole condition to include a and statement...

Comment: @CodeYard I changed the reply, elaborating more on how to improve thie code.